# How to create conditional column in Tableau?

Tags: tableau-desktop

I am new to Tableau and realized that Tableau is way different to power-BI. I am struct with this challenge in Tableau. I have data having ID as a column. I want to create a new column Repeated_ID which checks if the IDs in ID column are repeated. If an ID exists more than once in the column, Repeated_ID column should be "Yes" else "No".

This is how my result should look like:

```
ID Repeated_ID
1     Yes
2     No 
3     No
1     Yes
4     Yes
5     No
4     Yes
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a calculated field  : Repeated_ID

```
IF COUNT([ID]) > 1
    THEN "Yes"
ELSE "No"
END
```

Comment: Hi Bharath, do let us know if the code helped you